# Problem connecting Instruments to my iPod (touch) device

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, remote-debugging

I'm having a bit of trouble connecting intstruments to my App on a iPod touch device. Whilst debugging in the Simulator is possible, I get this error in instruments when trying to start a app:

> Target failed to run: Remote exception
>   encountered : 'Selector'
>   processIdentifierForBundleIdentifier:'
>   not authorized for type
>   'DTSpringBoardProcessControlService"

Thanks in advance

Comment: the problem does not occur any more with sdk4 … problem "solved".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem.  The current fix is to install XCode 3.2.2 in a different directory and use the Instruments.app in new directory.

Not much of a fix, but XCode 3.2.3 is still beta, so problems are expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the build you are deploying to your device when profiling is not the correct build.  By editing the scheme in xcode and changing "Release" to "Debug" you will get the debugging symbols you need to allow instruments to work.